# PhpStorm: running PHPUnit database tests from Docker container

Tags: docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I configured PhpStorm to run PHPUnit tests from Docker container. Unfortunately if test tries to connect to MySQL server I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

MySQL server runs in the same container. If I try to connect to MySQL server from container via some standalone script - it works fine.
Also the app itself works fine too.

Other tests (without database usage) work fine.

Any ideas what is wrong with my PhpStorm configuration? I followed official step by step configuration [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7aGWO6K3Ho), but it does not cover database part.

PhpStorm runs command that is being executed every time I hit run tests button:

```
docker://mycontainer/myapp:v1.0/php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --configuration /var/www/myapp/tests/phpunit.xml /var/www/myapp/tests/unit
```

Maybe problem is with phpstorm_helpers? Because it stands as separate container. Maybe my app container and helper container should be linked somehow?

Comment: That's an antipattern. One container, one task. You shouldn't run either your tests and your database server in the same container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I need is to run tests in existing container which I start only once. Depending on [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000099384-Run-tests-on-existing-docker-container) PhpStorm does not have such functionality yet.

So I switched to remote interpreter instead. Now PhpStorm connects to container via SSH. I know, it's a bit gruesome, but for this moment it's what I need.

Still if somebody wants to run integration tests with PhpStorm and Docker in proper way there is a good [thread](https://binary-data.github.io/2016/06/15/running-integration-tests-phpstorm-phpunit-docker/) about it.

Comment: Thanks @Bounce, do you know if there is a mirror for that article?